# TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int() with list

Tags: python

This is the code where i get the error:

```
linb = []  
cpt = 20   
temp = 0    
while cpt != 0:   
    linb.append(input("Plus que " + str(cpt) + " nombre a rentrer: "))   
    cpt -= 1   
for i in linb:   
    if i > temp:   
        temp = i   
print(temp)   
print(linb.index(temp))   '
```

This issu is for the "for i in linb:" but I can't convert i.. Linb is a list a number and temp a unique number.

Thanks for the help !!!

Answer (score 3):

`input` returns a string (`str`) which you must convert to an integer (`int`):

```
linb.append(int(input("Plus que " + str(cpt) + " nombre a rentrer: ")))
```

Comment: Thakns a lot !!